# Problem with javascript timer play sound in last 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, audio, timer

I've created a simple countdown timer in vuejs. setInterval is used to run every 0.1 second and when the time is 3 or 2 or 1 play a sound beep.mp3. (tried setTimeout is also not work).

The timer is work fine in iOS but not in android tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab A with default browser).

When the init time is set to 15 or higher, there is 0.3 - 0.5 second delay when playing the sound for 2 second

Work on Mac / iphone / android phone
https://youtu.be/3DeD78lZ2F8

Sound delay in last 2 seconds on Android Tablet with default browser & chrome browser
https://youtu.be/syRdIBXYmeU

No sound delay on the same android tablet with firefox
https://youtu.be/1T68LvV8QRU

any idea why this happen? Is it possibly is browser problem?

The timer code:

```
<template>
  <div class="white--text" style="font-size: 48px;">
    {{second}}
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <v-btn @click="timerStart">Start</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      default: 20,
      second: 20,
      num: 0.1,
      audio: new Audio(require('@/assets/audio/beep.mp3'))        
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    
  },
  methods: {
    timerStart() {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.second = parseFloat((this.second - this.num).toFixed(1))

        if (this.second == 3.0 || this.second == 2.0 || this.second == 1.0)
          this.audio.play() //<-- code run at this.second == 2 but sound played at 1.7 second 

        // Reset the timer
        if (this.second <= 0)
          this.second = this.default
      }, 100)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please include any code? It would help troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Yes, code is added. Thanks.

Comment: I've tested the timer in another android phone (3 years old phone and it is not expensive model) and it is working fine with no sound delay. I've no idea why the sound is delay in Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1 2019